# Property type of VBA object

Tags: excel, vba

Returned is "Compile error: definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, ParamArrary, or an invalid Set parameter".

I understand what this error is but just can't see why given it's so simple, sorry and thanks hopefully:

```
Private natural_persons As Collection
Private suspicous_reports As cls_SR
Private legal_persons As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set natural_persons = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Let natural_person(S As cls_NP)
    natural_persons.Add (S)
End Property

Public Property Get natural_person(S As Integer) As cls_NP
    natural_person = natural_persons(S)
End Property

Public Property Let suspicous_report(S As cls_SR)
    suspicous_reports = S
End Property

Public Property Get suspicous_report() As cls_SR
    suspicous report = suspicous_reports
End Property

Public Property Let legal_person(S As cls_LP)
    legal_persons.Add S
End Property

Public Property Get legal_person(S As Integer) As cls_LP
    legal_person = legal_persons(S)
End Property
```

Comment: object-type properties require `Set` in place of `Let`, and also need to use `Set` in assigning the return value.  Missing underscore here `suspicous report = suspicous_reports`

Comment: Also, you don't need the parenthesis around `S` in `natural_persons.Add (S)`

Answer (score 0):

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264197.aspx

> *arglist*
>
> Optional. List of variables representing arguments that are
> passed to the Property Get procedure when it is called. Multiple
> arguments are separated by commas. The name and data type of each
> argument in a Property Get procedure must be the same as the
> corresponding argument in a Property Let procedure (if one exists).

Your use of Properties here is not ideal (or - as you see - possible): instead of the `Property Let` you might instead consider an `AddXXX()` method and just have the Get